# Why does my web application running on WildFly 9 take very long to deploy?

Tags: web-applications, deployment, jboss, web-deployment, wildfly-9

My web application is running on WildFly 9 and the deployment takes a very long time. Sometimes, it exceeds the deployment-timeout and the deployment fails.

As per the log, the deployments halts at the below line for a long duration and then eventually timeout occurs.

```
JBWS022052: Starting JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 5.0.0.Final
```

Comment: could you please give us more info? Does your app deploy faster in another version of wildfly? have you made a change in your app?

Comment: I haven't compared it with other WildFly versions. Would you like any more specific information?

Comment: WildFly 9 Web Services subsystem is now based on JBossWS 5.0.0.Final and there are a lot of backward compatible changes as you can see [here](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/JBossWS5MigrationNotes). As your WildFly is hanging exactly in the Web Services part, your web services module may have adjustments to be done. Are your deploying your project and starting WildFly from some IDE like Eclipse? Do you start WildFly from within Eclipse? What is the error when timeout occurs?

Comment: What is the size of your application? The larger it is the more scanning involved generally speaking. Also make sure you don't include libraries already included in WildFly.